# Math vocab: operator on $S$ and into $S =$?

Tags: computer-science, terminology, definition

Is there a special name for a binary operation on the set $S$ that is also into $S$, that is unambiguous with other uses.  I.e.  if it's "operator on $S$", I've heard that in other places meaning the operator could map to another set $T$.  I'm working on a math library in the D language.

Comment: A *binary operation* on a set $S$ is, by definition, a map $S\times S\to S$. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: endomap: $S\times S \to S$

Comment: BTW the tag `(computer-science)` is not relevant. The context was already set by OP in his/her sentence: ".. the D language."

Comment: @J.D.: I don't like that: "endomap" suggests a map form a set to *itself*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the term [closed binary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation)? (other [reference](http://www.rowan.edu/open/depts/math/howe/BookChapters/Binary.pdf))

Comment: "Closed binary operation" is rather strange terminology. Instead, mathematicians usually say that a (sub)set is closed under a binary operation.

Comment: @BillDubuque I find it strange too, but it makes sense. At least, it does not makes any _other_ sense. Shall we conclude there is no unanimous terminology? There is [in French](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loi_de_composition_interne) and [German](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zweistellige_Verkn%C3%BCpfung): internal.